# how to create Map Markers on UIImageView?

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, android-mapview, markers

I am using static images in Imageview to show some area. I want to place pin markers that we can create on google maps.

What is a good way to implement this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please explain more.....

Comment: I am using static images of resolution 900X1000 pixels. In that image I have some Point of Interests on some coordinates. That I want create markers on that coordinates similar to google map kit. How to implement that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using google's static maps API.  If that's the case check out google's documentation, it seems to explain what you need pretty well (if I understood correctly).

[Google Static Maps API - Markers](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#Markers)